# Unable to browse IP using Browser after adding in Host File

Tags: dns, hosts

I have mapped an IP in my Host file
My IP 
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX myservername     server name is just a name without any "."

When i try to ping it from command prompt using
ping myservername it return proper ip

but when i try to browse it using the URL

```
http://myserver/webapplicationURL/myservice.svc?wsdl
```

Unable to determine IP address from host name for

Can anyone guide?

I am using Windows 7
Broswer I have tried are
Chrome  37.0.2062.120

Comment: which port are you using 80 ?

Comment: yes Port number 80

Comment: Read mine http://superuser.com/a/816136/354352 and replace 8080 with 80 and 1 up and down (79 , 81). If it did not worked then you should have a firewall problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have not advised which browser or OS you are using, but you probably need to restart your browser, and possibly ckear your DNS cache as well ([for example using ipconfig /flushdns](http://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/how-do-i-flush-my-windows-dns-cache/))

Comment: I have tried flushdns but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the DNS search domain after it.

You can find what it is via the following:`Cmd > ipconfig > Primary DNS suffix`

Answer (score 0):

Do you know why? Assuming your local ip is 127.0.0.1 and you have for example hosted your server on port 8080 then what will happen? Is it bound to your real IP (Public I mean)? NO!
This is what you are wrong in. You should enable it in your modem DMZ(Delimi(sth) Zone) or the use of Virtual servers.
Follow:

- Log in to your modem
- Go to Advanced Setup -> NAT
- If you dont see `DMZ` and `Virtual Server` on bottom, change `Virtual Circuit` until the two options appear.
- Basically DMZ is not suggested as it opens all your open ports to real world and it is a security issue so selection of Virtual Server should be a better choice.
- If you choose DMZ enter your network IP (ie 192.168.1.100 or whatever)
- If you select virtual server:

  > - Select **Application** or give it a name yourslef
  > - Select **Protocol** to be TCP (or choose UDP)
  > - Then select **Start Port Number** and **End Port Number** which if you wanna open 8080 for example, would be Start from 8079 and End to 8081.
  > - Enter your network ip in **Local IP Address**
- Save it and restart your modem. then each time you open 8080 port on your computer (your specific network IP) it automatically be bound to your public Ip Address. But be careful of security.